# Need help scraping this data in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a website with code that looks like this:

```
<div class="d-row js-wrapper" id="row-1"><div class="d-cell js-activator" data-label="type">Residential</div><div class="d-cell d-cell--break" data-label="Company">J Smith</div><div class="d-cell js-target" data-label="Location">UK</div><div class="d-cell js-target" data-label="ID">62144</div><div class="d-cell js-target" data-label="Ask
">730000</div><div class="d-cell js-target" data-label="email">None</div><div class="d-cell js-target" data-label="Contact time (GMT)">
                                8:00 am to 4:30 pm
                        </div> </div>

<div class="d-row js-wrapper" id="row-2"><div class="d-cell js-activator" data-label="type">Commercial</div><div class="d-cell d-cell--break" data-label="Company">JBloggs ltd</div><div class="d-cell js-target" data-label="Location">FR</div><div class="d-cell js-target" data-label="ID">55324</div><div class="d-cell js-target" data-label="Ask
">670000</div><div class="d-cell js-target" data-label="email">None</div><div class="d-cell js-target" data-label="Contact time (GMT)">
                                9:00 am to 5:30 pm
                        </div> </div>
```

I'd like to be able to scrape it into a pandas data frame. So far I've tried the following in selenium:

```
info = driver.find_element_by_class_name(".d-row")
print(info[0].text)
```

but that gives this:

```
Residential J Smith UK 62144 730000 None 8:00 am to 4:30 pm
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Which part of the data are you looking to scrape?

Comment: I would like all of the information in the data-labels, for example:

data-label="Location">UK
data-label="ID">62144

I would like the location, the id etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it missing `s` it should be `find_element[s]_by_class_name`, `.-d-row` is not valid value to use in that context it should be used for css selector and use `get_attribute()` to get element attribute

```python
for row in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".d-row"):
    for cell in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('.d-cell'):
        key = cell.get_attribute('data-label').strip()
        value = cell.text.strip()
        print("{}: {}".format(key, value))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about find all element with class contain d-cell and then get the attribute data-label

```
list_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "d-cell")]')
for element in list_elements:
   print(element.get_attribute("data-label"))
```